# TeamCity - How do you give feedback to clients for a deployment to their machine?

Tags: api, teamcity

Currently when our software is out of date, the following call is made to queue a deploy in TeamCity.

```
/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue={0}&system.name=TargetMachine&system.value={1}
```

Argument 0 being the buildTypeId and argument 1 being the hostname of the targetMachine.

We are trying to setup a way to give the client feedback on the status of their build in TeamCity.  Our idea was to create a website that would popup on a clients computer to show the status of their deployment in TeamCity, but can't figure out any quick way of doing this.  Keep in mind we dont want the client to see the whole queue, only their build.

The problem I am arising at is when calling TeamCity with the command above, there is no way that I know of to retrieve the created buildId.  If I could get the buildId, then the rest should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TeamCity [Windows Tray Notifier](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD3/Windows+Tray+Notifier) tool. You can configure  notificationf for different events like build started/finished/etc. Obviously if this is a case installing such a tool on the client's PC.

For instance, an user would see such popup window in case of build crash:

[image]

Also TeamCity allows configure email notification on the broad set of events related to a particular build or project.

Comment: That seems like a good option, but can you specify this to only show notifications for a specific environment variable such as machine name?